# R Leaflet: How to plot a map with a specific geographic location within addTiles Function?

Tags: r, ggplot2, leaflet

I tried plotting Delhi location using the addTiles function from Leaflet Package. Below is the code:

```
leaflet()%>%
addTiles(map = "Delhi",urlTemplate = "http://www.openstreetmap.org/search?query=delhi#map=11/28.6518/77.2219",attribution = 'Google')
```

Getting this error: Error in map$x : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

I searched for solutions but couldn't find an answer to my specific problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run this code

```
library(leaflet)
leaflet()%>%
  addTiles()%>%
  setView(lng = 77.209021,lat =28.613939,zoom = 10 )
```

Results

[image: delhi]

Comment: Your code was helpful. Could you please tell me how to did you get the Longitude and Latitude values.

Comment: to find the lat and long type a place name on this website [link](https://www.latlong.net)

Comment: Awesome. Very helpful!